# Modify Shared Preferences when app is closed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How I can modify a value from SharedPreferences, daily, even the application is closed? Something like a service to run in background.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to go a bit deepy: you wanna do it once a day or every time the app is closed?

Comment: I have a long value and i want to decrease a unit once a day.

Comment: You want to do it every day in any cases or only if the user open the app that certain day?

Comment: In any cases, even the user open on not the app.

Comment: so the best way is using an AlarmManager, if you want a quick guide have a look here :) https://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AlarmManager or JobScheduler to provide calling some callbacks with interval or with Calendar event. Then in appropriate callbacks (for example, for AlarmManager it's broadcast reciever with `onReceive` method) you can change your SharedPreference

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Alarm Service](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for time based operations even if your application is closed.